# How to use sed to delete lines not containing pattern

Tags: regex, linux, bash, unix, sed

I have a file as below:

```
Thumb Sri Lanka/Anuradhapura/Thumb Anuradhapura.jpg
Thumb Sri Lanka/Anuradhapura/vtour/panos/Anuradhapura.tiles/mobile/pano_b.jpg
Thumb Sri Lanka/Anuradhapura/vtour/panos/Anuradhapura.tiles/mobile/pano_d.jpg
Thumb Sri Lanka/Anuradhapura/vtour/panos/Anuradhapura.tiles/mobile/pano_f.jpg
Thumb Sri Lanka/Anuradhapura/vtour/panos/Anuradhapura.tiles/mobile/pano_l.jpg
Thumb Sri Lanka/Anuradhapura/vtour/panos/Anuradhapura.tiles/mobile/pano_r.jpg   
Thumb Sri Lanka/Anuradhapura/vtour/panos/Anuradhapura.tiles/mobile/pano_u.jpg
Thumb Sri Lanka/Anuradhapura/vtour/plugins/fps.xml
Thumb Sri Lanka/Anuradhapura/vtour/plugins/gyro2.js
```

I need to delete all lines except the first line, which means that lines should not be deleted if it contains `Thumb[any characters except /].jpg`.

I try to use `sed` to do this but I don't know how to write the regex.

I've tried like this: `sed -i -e '.*Thumb^(/)\.jpg!d' file` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Is not clear to me what's the difference between the first line and the 2on line (to be removed?). The blank space? Both fits the `Thumb[any characters except /].jpg` pattern you mention.

Comment: is grep with the parameter `-xv` not working properly?

Comment: @MarcM `Thumb` + `things containing slash` + `.jpg` --- delete. `Thumb` + `things not containing slash` + `.jpg` --- dont delete.

Comment: @Yves, show the desired result

Comment: try **perl**: `perl -lne 'print if /Thumb(?!.*\/).*jpg/' file`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If filename has to start with Thumb and then one or more charaters (without slash) and and with jpg, you can use regex like this one:

```
Thumb[^\/]*\.jpg
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/Qrz7O8/1)

Comment: I've tried `sed -i -e '#Thumb[^\/]*\.jpg#!d' file`, it still doesn't work.

Comment: sed -i -e '/Thumb[^\/]*\.jpg/!d' file   --- This works. Thanks.

Comment: @Yves You can mark this answer as a solution as a way to say thanks :-)